# question about transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, private-blockchain

If BOB have  1 Ether and Send it to alice, and at the same time send 1 lip to Eve , because the first transaction not mined yet

How  i can make sure that BOB can't send double transaction after confirme the first yet ?